# How to stop dataGridView from moving to next row on Enter while in editMode

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't seem to figure out how to keep the `DataGridView` from moving to the next row after pressing *Enter* while in *EditMode*. Currently after pressing *Enter* and committing my edit I'd like to keep the cell in focus AND in *EditMode*!

Comment: Why? Are you doing multiline text?

Comment: @BartoszKP, because I want to know whether to spend effort answering. If it is stupid I won't. If I spend 3 minutes on question worth only 30 seconds, that is a loss to humanity as a whole.

Comment: @BartoszKP, I answered that already. I just want to know if it is worth my effort. If it is, I might help. If not, not. If OP doesn't answer, I will assume not. Is that so hard to understand?